# Conditional to change circle size creates multiple circles instead

Tags: processing

The program increases the diameter of a circle when the UP arrow key is pressed, and decreases it with the DOWN arrow key. However, when I press the down key, it creates smaller circles over the original one, instead of reducing its size.

Photo: https://i.ibb.co/HgNfCMM/new-circles.png

I suspect the up key is doing the same, but the effect isn't noticeable. How do I make it so that it changes the diameter of the already existing circle, instead of making new ones?

```
int X;

void setup(){
  size(400, 400);
  fill(#FFFF00);
}

void draw() {
  circle(200, 200, X + 30);

  if (keyPressed) {
    if (key == CODED) {
      if (keyCode == UP) {
        if (X <= 300) {
          X = X + 5;
        }
      }
      if (keyCode == DOWN) {
        if (X >= 30) {
          X = X - 5;
        }
      }
    }
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding a background() call at the top of draw() so that previous circle is overdrawn.

```
int X;
color BLUE = color(64,124,188);

void setup(){
  size(400, 400);
  fill(#FFFF00);
}

void draw() {
  background(BLUE);
  circle(200, 200, X + 30);

  if (keyPressed) {
    if (key == CODED) {
      if (keyCode == UP) {
        if (X <= 300) {
          X = X + 5;
        }
      }
      if (keyCode == DOWN) {
        if (X >= 30) {
          X = X - 5;
        }
      }
    }
  }

}
```

Comment: Thank you, it worked! I'm curious, can you explain why putting a background call before the circle on draw() solves the issue? I'm guessing it's because both are executed once per frame, but the background is executed first, and continously being drawn over all the previous circles?

Comment: Your guess is correct.  You can read more about background() here: https://processing.org/reference/background_.html